# Проблема с методом messages.setActivity в библиотеке vk_api

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, библиотеки

Есть код, который должен поддерживать статус, что я что либо пишу в беседу:

```py
import vk_api
from random import randint
import time

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='тут был токен с доступом к сообщениям')
vk = vk_session.get_api()


while True:
    vk.messages.setActivity(type='typing', peer_id='200000000092')
    print('Активен')
    time.sleep(3)
```

Но он выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vlabey/PycharmProjects/FludBot/trumo.py", line 11, in <module>
    vk.messages.setActivity(type='typing', peer_id='200000000092')
  File "/home/vlabey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vk_api/vk_api.py", line 671, in __call__
    return self._vk.method(self._method, kwargs)
  File "/home/vlabey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vk_api/vk_api.py", line 636, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied
```

С обычными диалогами всё работает

Comment: Кстати, Вы можете ждать подольше. ВК отображает статус печати в течение 10 секунд. Как мне кажется, оптимальным вариантом будет 6-7.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, обязательно воспользуюсь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неверно указали `peer_id`. Должно быть 10 цифр.
Имеется в виду математическое сложение для его получения.

Попробуйте заменить на `2000000092`